# Firebase get length of object / number of children in object

Tags: javascript, firebase

Is there a way to get the number of children of an object without downloading the entire object? From what I understand using `numChildren` would first download the entire object, would it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, currently it would. Getting the number of children without downloading the entire object is currently not possible (though it may be a feature added in the future).

As a work-around, you may try storing the length in a separate location in Firebase (and update its value whenever children are added or removed).

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get a count of all currently active clients, but the only way it seems possible right now is to do a total download as there seems to be no way to do a transaction on disconnect?

Comment: That's also correct, you can't do a transaction on disconnect (yet). We're aware this is a problem for presence, and something we're working on resolving ASAP!